# Datatable skip duplicate records (Distinct)

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicates, distinct

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='db.mdb';");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table where col1 Is Null order by date asc", con);
OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
adap.Fill(dt);
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

How to skip some results my datagridview?

Thanks for help.

Comment: duplicate based on what ?

Comment: select distinct can't work datatable, it's returned 0 row

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to fetch DISTINCT records from database and then bind them to datagridview.

```
string query = "SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table WHERE col1 IS NULL ORDER BY date";
```

However I noticed that you are ordering by `date`, But you have not selected `date` so you can not use it on `ORDER BY` clause.

Alternatively, If you want your data filtered on the front end then you can use this:

```
DataTable distinctRecords = new DataTable();
records = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, column1, column2 ...);
```